# Toggle multiple sidebars with separate map markers using Leaflet sidebar V2

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Using Sidebar V2 (https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2) I've managed to create a sidebar and have a (leaflet.js) map marker that opens and close the sidebar using a 'toggleSidebar' function.

```
var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar').addTo(map);
var sidebarDiv = document.getElementById('sidebar');

toggleSidebar = function() {
  if (hasClass(sidebarDiv,'collapsed')) {
    sidebar.open();
  } else {
    sidebar.close();
  }
}

function hasClass(element, cls) {
  return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

var map = L.map("map");
map.setView([51.2, 7], 9);

// MARKER 1: ENGLAND
var marker = L.marker([52.5868, -2.1257], 
    {title: 'test', 
    riseOnHover: true, 
    autoPanOnFous: true,
    maxZoom: 28}
    ).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
    toggleSidebar();
});
```

Looking at the above code it seems that my 'marker' doesn't have any way of accessing the sidebar element ID, which is why I'm struggling to create a second marker that opens/closes a second sidebar.

Using Sidebar v1 I could do the following:

```
var marker1 = L.marker([52.6369, -1.1398], 
    {title: 'United Kingdom', 
    riseOnHover: true, 
    autoPanOnFous: true,
    maxZoom: 28}
    ).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
    sidebar1.toggle();
});
```

..so each marker could connect to each individual sidebar, but this can't be done with v2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try creating array of marker objects and bind `click` event to each then you can either have another array of sidebars or just create it dynamically onclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've to change the function toggleSidebar a bit, so that it takes the id of the sidebar:

```
toggleSidebar = function(ID) {
  let sidebarDiv = document.getElementById(ID);
  if (hasClass(sidebarDiv,'collapsed')) {
    sidebar.open();
  } else {
    sidebar.close();
  }
}
```

and the callings are then

```
toggleSidebar('sidebar1');
toggleSidebar('sidebar2');
```

Assumed you had an eventHandler on a sidebar (which you haven't in your code) you could inside the handler also use:

```
toggleSidebar(this.id);
```

It might not work out of the box, likely you have to adjust some details till it's working but the fundamental idea is clear I hope.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! this is very useful. I think I'll figure it out with this. Cheers